# Ошибка: Unsatisfield forward or external declaration: 'MyRegEx.Split'

Tags: delphi, ооп

Почему в моем коде возникает ошибка?

> Unsatisfield forward or external declaration: 'MyRegEx.Split'

```
unit MyRegularExspressions;
interface
type
  RecArray = record
  sets: set of char;    //множ-во допустимых символов
  case bool: boolean of
    true:  (kvant: char);  //квантификатор
    false: (fir: word;     //первый индекс предела
             las: word;)    //второй индекс предела
  end;

  ResultMatch = record
    str: string;   //множ-во симв удовл маске
    index: word;   //индекс с котор начин множ-во симв
  end;

  IndRecArr = array of RecArray;   //основной массив(множ-во поиска и кол-во повторений)
  arrstring = array of string;
  ArrResultMatch = array of ResultMatch;

  MyRegEx = class
  PRIVATE
    mask: string;    //маска поика
    input: string;   //текст поиска
    IndexRecArr:  IndRecArr;

    Function Split(const input: string): arrstring;
    Procedure FillRecArr(const a: arrstring; var IndexRecArr: IndRecArr);
    Procedure DefinitReiterat(const a: arrstring; var IndexRecArr: IndRecArr);
  PUBLIC
    Constructor Create(NewMask: string);
    Function Matches(const input: string): ArrResultMatch;
    Function Match(const input: string): ArrResultMatch;
  end;


implementation
uses SysUtils;

Function Split(const input: string): arrstring;
begin
   ...
end;
  ...
end.
```

Comment: функции у вас в классе описаны, они не абстрактные, а кода к ним нет. Внизу есть код `Split()` но должен то быть `MyRegEx.Splt()`

Comment: почитайте еще про соглашения об именовании и т.п. типы данных обычно пишут с префиксом `T`, поля начинают c `F`, модификаторы доступа в верхнем регистре первый раз вижу и т.д.

Comment: @teran Мне кажется, даже если ответ короткий, но действительно является ответом (т.е. решает проблему), лучше его оформлять не как комментарий, а именно как ответ, чуть более подробно изложив.

Comment: @m.vokhm это да, времени не было на написание большого текста, а поскольку к вопросу долгое время никто не отвечал, то решил оставить коммент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что написанный вами код для `Split` из раздела `implementation` является **обычной функцией**, в то время как `Split` из раздела `interface` подразумевается **методом класса** `MyRegEx`. Так что объявлять его в разделе `implementation`, а потом и обращаться к нему, нужно соответствующим образом: как `MyRegEx.Split`.

```
interface
  type
    MyRegEx = class
    private
      ...
      function Split(const input: string): arrstring;
      ...
    public
      ...
    end;

implementation

function MyRegEx.Split(const input: string): arrstring;
begin
 ...
end;
```

В вашем же коде, внизу вы фактически объявляете одноимённую, самую обычную функцию `Split`, а предварительное объявление `MyRegEx.Split` остаётся неудовлетворённым, о чём и сообщает компилятор.

---

**UPD**, *спасибо за него @kami*

Избегать подобных ошибок в будущем может помочь комбинация клавиш `Ctrl+Shift+C`, которая, будучи нажатой в окружении кода объявления объекта, автоматически подставляет заготовки необходимых методов в раздел `implementation`.

Также стоит упомянуть об определённых стилевых соглашениях в Delphi:

- Объявляемые типы (и классы тоже) следует начинать с буквы `T`: `TRecArray`, `TArrString`, `TMyRegEx`, ...
- Поля класса (переменные, хранимые в объекте) с буквы `F`: `FMask`,     `FInput`, `FIndexRecArr`, ...
- Ключевые слова языка (вроде `private`, `public`) обычно пишут в нижнем регистре.
- Правильно расставить отступы может помочь `Ctrl+D`, если ваша [IDE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) это поддерживает.

Подробнее можно почитать об этом, например, [здесь](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=1288).

*В коде выше оставил изначальный стиль, чтобы не путать человека.*

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста информацию о `Ctrl+Shift+C` и о соглашении наименований классов.

Comment: Ого, «век живи - век учись», не знал об этой комбинации клавиш, всегда такие вещи сам писал, спасибо)

Comment: замечу, на всякий случай, что классы не всегда начинаются с `T`, например атрибуты RTTI.